# Is there a way to send files on Azure Service Bus with topics and subscriptions in Python?

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

**Summarize the problem:**

I am trying to send CSV files on Azure Service Bus with topics and subscriptions. I am following the official quick-start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/servicebus?view=azure-python) and successfully connected ASB with message printed. The next step I want to do is to send CSV files on ASB for a listener to copy the files. The CSV files are currently located inside a docker. Is it possible to send CSV files? if so, how? Any useful sources that could guide me into the right direction are much appreciated.

**What I've tried:**

Topics and subscriptions are already created by another team. Connection string only has rights to send and listen. Basically just following the quick-start:

```
from azure.servicebus.control_client import ServiceBusService, Message, Topic, Rule, DEFAULT_RULE_NAME

conString = '<connection string>'  

azure_namespace = 'abc'
key_name = 'xyz'
key_value = '1q2w3e4r5t6y7u8i9o='

bus_service = ServiceBusService(
    service_namespace=azure_namespace,
    shared_access_key_name=key_name,
    shared_access_key_value=key_value)
    
conTopic = 'mytopic'
conSubscription = 'mysubscription'

# send message to a topic 
for i in range(5):
    msg = Message('Msg {0}'.format(i).encode('utf-8'))
    bus_service.send_topic_message(conTopic, msg)
    
# receive messages from a subscription 
msg = bus_service.receive_subscription_message(conTopic, conSubscription)
print(msg.body)
```

Thank you all for the help

**EDIT:**

Ok after doing some digging, Blob Storage is a way to try it out. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325171/best-practice-for-sending-large-messages-on-servicebus/28940872) is another question posted on SO for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the right service for it. Messages on Service Bus has size limit. What you can do is add the file to Blob Storage, then add a message to the Service Bus with the file name or path

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look into the option.

Comment: Any ways we could use the workflow as you described to send a message to the Service Bus? Files are uploaded to Blob Storage. Would you please point me to the right direction on how to achieve the goal here?

Comment: right after send the files you can add a message to a queue, or you can use Event Grid integration, which will trigger an event after that. Then, you can use Logic Apps or Azure Functions to add a message to the Service Bus

Comment: Thanks for your response and guide. I will look into this.