# Read csv file lines and send them to azure service bus

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azureservicebus

I hope somebody can help to solve this doubt.

I have a csv file with some data, and I would like to read a csv file line by line and send those lines to a azure service bus.

Looking into Microsoft documentation, I found this solution:

```
# import os
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

CONNECTION_STR = "<NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING>"
QUEUE_NAME = "<QUEUE NAME>"

def send_batch_message(sender):
    batch_message = sender.create_message_batch()
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            batch_message.add_message(ServiceBusMessage("Message inside a ServiceBusMessageBatch"))
        except ValueError:
            # ServiceBusMessageBatch object reaches max_size.
            # New ServiceBusMessageBatch object can be created here to send more data.
            break
    sender.send_messages(batch_message)
    print("Sent a batch of 10 messages")

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)


print("Done sending messages")
print("-----------------------")
```

I was wondering if this is a good solution or if there is another best approach.

The reason behind this, is that I have a logstash processing some syslog and storing them in a csv file, and I need to send the content of those file to a azure service bus.

Thank you so much for your time and help guys.

Comment: You can add Syslog to Blob Storage and then send it to the Azure service bus.
You can refer to [Is there a way to send files on Azure Service Bus with topics and subscriptions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380646/is-there-a-way-to-send-files-on-azureservice-bus-with-topics-and-subscriptions) and  [Best practice for sending large messages on ServiceBus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325171/best-practice-for-sending-large-messages-on-servicebus/28940872)

Comment: I am trying to go for the direct option. without having to store anything in a blob storage. because if I store it in a blob storage, then I will need a event grid and a web hook to detect changes and run the command. This solution I think is the best, but I am having problems with the size limit while sending the queues. I have another post regarding this , this topic `Azure Service Bus send csv rows to queue`